# how to pass the control id in doPostBack?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can the attribute href be passed a doPostBack. Below is what I am trying but it leads to a  unexpected identifier error.

```
$('.pk_planner_name_container a').attr('href','javascript:doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pkHeaderControl$lnkSave',' ')');
```

Comment: You shouldn't "bind" event handlers like this. Make full use of jQuery (http://learn.jquery.com/events/). But for this particular piece of code, have a look at the quotation marks. `ctl00$Content...` is not part of the string.

Comment: Thanks Felix, I am actually struggling with the quotation marks. Now I am using $('.pk_planner_name_container a').attr('href','javascript:doPostBack(ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pkHeaderControl$lnkSave,'')'); and it now gives an unexpected string error

Comment: You put two strings after each other `'javascript:doPostBack(ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pkHeaderControl‌​$lnkSave,'` and `')'`, which is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes break the code.

```
$('.pk_planner_name_container a')     
.attr('href','javascript:doPostBack("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$pkHeaderControl$lnkSave","")');
```